# What is the best way to use lookup tables in QlikView?

Tags: qlikview

In QlikView, I have a table **Data** and one database table **A**. Table **A** should be used twice (**A_Left**, **A_Right**). (Table A can have thousands of entries.)

My load script is:

```
A_Left:
Load a_id_left,
     a_name_left
inline [
  a_id_left, a_name_left
  1, 'nwsnd'
  2, 'dcsdcws'
  3, 'fsdf'    ];

A_Rigtht:
Load a_id_right,
     a_name_right
inline  [
  a_id_right, a_name_right
  1, 'nwsnd'
  2, 'dcsdcws'
  3, 'fsdf'    ];

Data:
Load id, 
     a_id_left,
     a_name_left as 'Name_Left',
     a_id_right,
     a_name_right as 'Name_Right',
     data
inline [
  id, a_id_left, a_right_id, data
  1, 1, 2, 37
  1, 1, 3, 18
  1, 2, 3, 62
];
```

So my question is: What is the best way to use lookup tables in QlikView?
(Should I use `MAPPING` and/or `ApplyMap`? Why? Is that faster?)

One other part of the question is: Would it help change the data structure from star to table? 
(I know that would cost more memory.) And, by the way: How could I put all data in one table
so that I can store it completely in one QVD file?

Thanks for help an ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple lookups where you wish to look up a *single* value from another value you can use a `MAPPING` load and then use the `ApplyMap()` function. For example, say I have the following table:

```
LOAD
   *
INLINE [
   UserID, System
   1, Windows
   2, Linux
   3, Windows
];
```

I have another table that contains UserID and UserName as follows:

```
LOAD
   *
INLINE [
   UserID, UserName
   1, Alice
   2, Bob
   3, Carol
];
```

I can then combine the above tables with `ApplyMap` as follows:

```
UserNameMap:
MAPPING LOAD
   *
INLINE [
   UserID, UserName
   1, Alice
   2, Bob
   3, Carol
];

SystemData:
LOAD
   UserID,
   ApplyMap('UserNameMap', UserID, 'MISSING') as UserName,
   System
INLINE [
   UserID, System
   1, Windows
   2, Linux
   3, Windows
];
```

ApplyMap is very fast and should not significantly slow down your load time (although it will not be as fast as a direct QVD load). **However**, as mentioned ApplyMap can only be used if you wish to map a *single* value into your table. For more fields, you will need to use a `join` (which is similar to a SQL JOIN) if you wish to combine your results into a single table.

If you do not wish to join them into a single table (but keep it as a "star" scheme), just make sure that the fields that you wish to link are named the same. For example:

```
A_Left:
Load a_id_left,
     a_name_left as [Name_Left]
inline [
  a_id_left, a_name_left
  1, 'nwsnd'
  2, 'dcsdcws'
  3, 'fsdf'    ];

A_Rigtht:
Load a_id_right,
     a_name_right as [Name_Right]
inline  [
  a_id_right, a_name_right
  1, 'nwsnd'
  2, 'dcsdcws'
  3, 'fsdf'    ];

Data:
Load id, 
     a_id_left,
     a_id_right,
     data
inline [
  id, a_id_left, a_right_id, data
  1, 1, 2, 37
  1, 1, 3, 18
  1, 2, 3, 62
];
```

(I have removed your "name" fields from "Data" as it would fail to load).

This will then work in your QlikView document due to QlikView's automatic field associativity.

However, if you wish to have the data in a single table (e.g. for output to QVD) then in your case you will need to `JOIN` your two tables into `Data`. We can rearrange some of the tables to make our life a bit easier, if we put your `Data` table first, we can then join your other two tables on:

```
Data:
Load id, 
     a_id_left,
     a_id_right,
     data
inline [
  id, a_id_left, a_id_right, data
  1, 1, 2, 37
  1, 1, 3, 18
  1, 2, 3, 62
];

LEFT JOIN (Data)
Load a_id_left,
     a_name_left as [Name_Left]
inline [
  a_id_left, a_name_left
  1, 'nwsnd'
  2, 'dcsdcws'
  3, 'fsdf'    ];

LEFT JOIN (Data)
Load a_id_right,
     a_name_right as [Name_Right]
inline  [
  a_id_right, a_name_right
  1, 'nwsnd'
  2, 'dcsdcws'
  3, 'fsdf'    ];
```

This will then resort in a single table named "Data" which you can then output to QVD etc.

You may wish to think about optimising your "Table A" extract since it is almost being loaded twice, this may take some time (e.g. from long distance server etc.) so it may be better to grab your data in one go and then slice it once it's in memory (much faster). A quick example could be like the below:

```
TableA:
LOAD
     a_id_left,
     a_id_right,
     a_name_left,
     a_name_right
FROM ...;

Data:
Load id, 
     a_id_left,
     a_id_right,
     data
inline [
  id, a_id_left, a_id_right, data
  1, 1, 2, 37
  1, 1, 3, 18
  1, 2, 3, 62
];

LEFT JOIN (Data)
LOAD DISTINCT
     a_id_left,
     a_name_left as [Name_Left]
RESIDENT TableA;

LEFT JOIN (Data)
LOAD DISTINCT
     a_id_right,
     a_name_right as [Name_Right]
RESIDENT TableA;

DROP TABLE TableA;
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the last part, you can use the CONCATENATE function to append the contents of one table to anoher, i.e.

```
Final:
Load *
from
   Table1

CONCATENATE

Load *
from
   Table2
```

will give you one table, called Final with the merged contents of Table1 and Table2.